# Can Algebraic Limit Theorem apply to the function in exponential position?

Tags: limits, analysis, exponential-function

If I try to calculate this limit,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^ { x+1 }}$$
I go through these steps:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^ {{x} \cdot { \frac{x+1}{x} }}}$$

$$e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} {\frac{x+1}{x}}}$$

And I have a question about How the limit can be distributed. So, more precisely, what conditions are needed to make this possible? 
$$\lim {f(x)}^{g(x)} = \left(\lim f(x) \right)^{\lim g(x)}$$
Is the only condition that $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ converge needed to make this possible, or are there any more conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)^{g(x)} &= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \exp\left(\log(f(x)^{g(x)})\right)\\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \exp\left(g(x)\log(f(x))\right)\\
&= \exp\left(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)\log(f(x))\right)\\
&= \exp\left(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \log(f(x))\right)\\
&= \exp\left(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) \cdot \log(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x))\right)\\
&= \ldots \\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)^{\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)},
\end{align*}
so what you need is the existence of the limits and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=A>0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=B$ so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=A^B.$$
Indeed, since there is $\epsilon>0$ for which $f(x)>0$ for all $|x|>\epsilon,$  $e^x$ and $\ln$ they are continuous functions, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{g(x)\ln{f(x)}}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\ln{f(x)}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\ln\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)}= e^{B\ln{A}}=A^B.$$

Answer (score 0):

$exp(x) = e^{x}$ is a continuous function and if we have $a^{b}$ with $a>0$ we can rewritte $a^{b} = e^{b\ln(a)}$ , then if $f(x)>0$ and there exist $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)\ln(f(x)) = L$ then there exist $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x))^{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{g(x)\ln(f(x))} = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)\ln(f(x))} = e^{L}$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^{x+1} = $$
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^{x} \cdot \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)\right) = $$
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) = $$
$$ e \cdot 1 = $$
$$ e $$